# Double ToolTip on same mouseover using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having a problem in using the tooltip from wz_tooltip.js on a while function.
I want when I use the mouseover function for the tooltip to appear , I want to make 2 of them with separate text for each other.

When I'm using the double quotes only one of them is appearing. 
Where is my code wrong and doesen't make the second tooltip appear next to it and to have different size and text?

```
  echo "
    <a href=\"".$optiune."\" onmouseover=
    \"Tip('<div class=split-para>Tip:".$informatie['tip']."<span>(si aici raritatea)</span></div>
    <br> <center>".$informatie['nume_ro']."     ".$variabila_echipat." ".$variabila_enchant." 
    </center>   ".$variabila_putere."       ".$variabila_procent_putere."       
    ".$variabila_dex."      ".$variabila_procent_dexteritate."      ".$variabila_rez."      
    ".$variabila_procent_rezistenta."       ".$variabila_carisma."      
    ".$variabila_procent_carisma."      ".$variabila_intel."        
    ".$variabila_procent_inteligenta."      ".$variabila_pret_cumparare."       
    ".$variabila_atac."     ".$variabila_procent_atac."     ".$variabila_aparare."      
    ".$variabila_procent_aparare."      ".$variabila_posibilitatea_daune."      
    ".$variabila_daune_min."        ".$variabila_procent_daune_minime."     
    ".$variabila_daune_max."            ".$variabila_procent_daune_maxime."             
    ".$variabila_viata."        ".$variabila_viata_reg."        ".$variabila_mana."     
    ".$variabila_mana_reg."     ".$variabila_enchant_grad_tip."     ".$variabila_cantitate."    
    ".$variabila_posibilitate_vanzare."  ".$variabila_pret_vanzare." <center><br>   
    ".$variabila_posibilitate_echipare." ".$mesaj_set." <br><br> ".$variabila_niv_min." 
    </center>')
    ;\"Tip(' test ')\"


    onmouseout=\"UnTip()\">

    <img src='".$informatie['cale_imagine']."/".$informatie['imagine'].".png' 
     alt=".$informatie['id']." ></a>

    ";
```

The whole function is retriving some info for some objects and echo it when you user the mouseover over some picture.

I want when I use the mouse over that picture , 2 tooltips in the right of the picture not only one

Here's a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/alexgoaga/yjv1Ltre/1/ , press ok when the error appears

Thank you :)

Comment: can you please supply the rendered html from your page

Comment: here is : http://www.speedyshare.com/Pw59D/site.rar , please use the "slow download" button for not having problems

Comment: please copy and paste the relevant rendered html into your original question. SO doesnt encourage the download of files for the purpose of assisting with questions

Comment: How i can do that ? just copy and paste here in the question the full html page? how about the js or css?

Comment: please find only the relevant tooltip html. This should be from the page you can view in your browser (the rendered version of your `php` file(s)). It would be best if you use something like http://jsfiddle.net to display the html, css and js as needed

Comment: doned . updated in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, unfortunately it looks like the way wz_tooltip works is by adding a `div` element to the `body` and then toggling its visibility, contents and position.

Unfortunately that means that you will likely need to add both of your desired elements inside the one tooltip if you want to keep using wz_tooltip.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="Tip('<div id=\'element1\'>section1</div><div id=\'element2\'>section2</div>');" onmouseout="UnTip()">
    <img src="http://84.232.199.159/img/items/ar_bow.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#WzTtDiV{
    overflow:visible !important;
}
#WzBoDy{
    background:none !important;
    border:none !important;
    outline:none !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;
}
#element1,
#element2{
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
}
#element1{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:20px;
    width:auto;
    padding:0 30px;
    background:blue;
}
#element2{
    top:30px;
    left:20px;
    height:40px;
    width:auto;
    background:red;
}
```

Have a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/yjv1Ltre/2/)